# implement Interface in an abstract class

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Is it possible to implement the interface in an abstract class and change the implemented interface method into abstract?

```
interface ITest
{
    string GetData();
    int ProcessData();
}

public abstract class MyAbstract:ITest
{
    public int Process()
    {
        // some code
    }

    public abstract string GetData(); // Change the implemented method into abstract Is it Possible?
}
```

Comment: probably duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395298/c-sharp-abstract-class-implements-interface-bad-coding-practice

Comment: Thanks for your immediate replies guys, but my question is if i implement interface method and change that method into abstract is possible or not. `public abstract string GetData()`

Comment: Are you asking whether it's possible to change a non-abstract method into an abstract one?

Comment: did you read all the answers of the above post ? your answer is there in that post.

Comment: @FosterZ: I don't believe it's a dupe because: a) that question is not constructive, b) the example given in that question doesn't deal specifically with having abstract members implementing the interface, it only revolves around with implementing the interface on the abstract class *in any way* (not whether or not it's actually possible, and it doesn't give as an example this case); this question deals specifically with that case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it. Simply add the abstract keyword and remove the implementation. There's obviously a pitfall with this. Any class which inherits from your abstract class will have to implement `GetData` themselves now. Depending on how many classes are children of `MyAbstract`, this may lead to a lot of work and code duplication.

In your case, where the method in question is declared by the interface which `MyAbstract` implements, you can actually just drop `GetData` completely and rely on the declaration of this function in `ITest`.